# How to find a value in a 2d hashtable in C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, iterator, hashtable

I have this 2d hashatable :

```
map<char, map<string, string>> hashtable;
```

And I want to check if this value : hashtable['a']["Sa"] exist or not. How to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please do not include 'thank' in posts. See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: First, do you know how to check if a value in a 1D `map` exists?

Comment: @user202729 That is not specified in the Standard, but typical implementation uses some form of BST.

Comment: By the way, c++ `map` cannot be a hash table, because it must keep the keys ordered.

Comment: @user202729 what do you mean ordered?

Comment: [sorted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to check if `hashtable['a']` exists, then retrieve the second element of the map, and then check for the next one.

```
auto it = hashtable.find('a');
if (it != hashtable.end()) {
    auto it2 = it->second.find("Sa");
    if(it2 != it->second.end()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
return false;
```

The method `find()` returns an iterator equal to the end of the map if the element does not exist.

Comment: when I write this code:

auto it = hashtable.find('a');

visual c 2008 gives me this error:

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator' to 'int'

Comment: @sosscs Then you're not using C++11.

Comment: Then just replace auto by map<char, map<string, string>>::iterator on the first one and map<string, string>::iterator on the second one.